# Joining on a one-row table: subquery or cross join?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-execution-plan

- *query no.1*

  ```
  select 
        table2.someClmn,table1.name,table1.address 
  from 
        table1 cross join table2 
  where table1.id = 123
  ```
- *query no.2*

  ```
    select 
         (select someClmn from table2),table1.name,table1.address 
    from table1
    where table1.id = 123
  ```

---

Both *queries* return exact same result so which is good to use?
NOTE: in my case `table2` contains single row only

---

EXPLAIN ANALYZE for [*query no.1*](http://explain.depesz.com/s/1yUs) and [*query no.2*](http://explain.depesz.com/s/SLTG)

Comment: Compare the output of `explain analyze`. THough the second should fail with an error unless there's a `WHERE ...` clause in the subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the explain output and with the special case factor that `table2` contains only one row, I'd expect the second plan to be faster.

Avoiding that nested loop will be a significant win.

Note that if the subquery were a normal correlated subquery with a WHERE clause, not this one-row uncorrelated subquery, things would be different. The two queries would probably then result in the same plan.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the query you (and others) can read and understand best since there shouldn't be that much of a performance issue.

Comment: be specific, which query you're suggesting??

Comment: For me personally, query 1 seems like something you understand faster because the join is more obvious. If you read quick, a "from table2" can easy become a "from table1" because you are in the scope. A "cross join" is more visible.